# BizTalk 2013 R2 Receive Pipeline Error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm getting this error message when I submit the input file (which BizTalk eats up as expected)...

```
There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: 

"FileName.BizTalk.Pipelines.Receive_ResponsePipeline, 
 FileName.BizTalk.Pipelines, 
 Version=1.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=040e2e09e19196ce" 

Source: "Unknown " 

Receive Port: "rcv_Response" 

URI: "C:\Data\drops\in\*.txt" 

Reason:  Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft      
BizTalk Server 2013 R2\Pipeline Components\FileName.BizTalk.Core.dll' or one of its  
dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked that directory and the DLL it's looking for is there. I even rebuilt it from the solution along with all its dependencies.

Could this simply be a case of a corrupt file/installation or could it be something else?

The BizTalk solution builds with no issues and I was able to deploy to the BizTalk Server without issues.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a BizTalk pipeline component, you need to:

1. Add the file to the "Pipeline Components" folder as the error suggest.
2. Add it to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Make sure you restart the host instance(s) after deployment AND be sure to deploy it on all BizTalk servers within the BizTalk Group.

Comment: The file is there and we did deploy it to the GAC.  There is only one BizTalk server within this group.  The error persists.

Comment: 1) Do the name, SNK PublicKeyToken and assembly version number match exactly the one that is referenced by the Pipeline?  2) Does the Pipeline Component have any dependencies?  If so are they deployed to the GAC?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few check points that may be cause of issue:

- Check if all the dependent assemblies(Required/imported in given assemby) are also present in GAC & wherever necessary. Any missing dependent assembly gives the same error.
- Receive Location handler (check if it is 32 or 64 bit host)
- Check if the receive handler is running on all nodes of the farm, if
  yes check required dlls are in place
- Does EDI component has been properly installed on production box
- Check if your project is properly build from Visual Studio, probably
  clean the solution and then rebuilt and deploy from VS on dev
  environment and then move to prod
- After deployment hosts are restarted
- Check if receive handler is defined for the host instance `Adapters-->File-->New-->Receive Handler` and check if the `HostInstance` is added.  Check `Receive Location` and updated the Receive Handler property.
- Check the application pool to Integrated and targeted the v4.0 Framework.  This clears the initial error, but then you can receive a new error from IIS that the svc handler was not correctly mapped.  I then realized that I needed to run the "`aspnet_regiis.exe -I`" command against the correct version of aspnet_regiis (the v4.0 framework version).

Sources:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/246d306b-5a18-497d-a4f6-f8b3a9aacdb8/receive-pipeline-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly?forum=biztalkgeneral

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7204.biztalk-server-list-of-errors-and-warnings-causes-and-solutions.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joscot/archive/2013/08/14/biztalk-2013-hosted-wcf-service-fails-because-it-could-not-load-microsoft-biztalk-interop-ssoclient.aspx?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer52156&utm_medium=twitter